# In my final answers regarding pressure vessel design problem can't satisfy the constraints , which needs to be muliple of 0.0625

Tags: matlab, gcd-and-lcm, constraints

I need to solve a pressure vessel design problem. The objective is to minimize the total cost, including the cost of material, forming and welding.

The solution has four values `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and `x4` where:
`x1` is the thickness of the shell
`x2` is the thickness of the head
`x3` is the inner radius (R)
and  `x4` is the length of cylindrical section of the vessel.

One constraint of this problem is, `x1` and `x2` should be integer multiples of `0.0625`. Despite getting superior result, my algorithm doesn't satisfy this constraint. I have provided the objective function and function for constraints in my MATLAB code. How to satisfy those constraint in my final answer?

The minimization problem can be stated as:

```
function y = PrPf(x)
y = 0.6224*x(1)*x(3)*x(4)+1.7781*x(2)*x(3)^2+3.1661*x(1)^2*x(4)+19.84*x(1)^2*x(3);
```

And the function for constraints in MATLAB is:

```
function [g,geq]=constraint(x)
%Inequality constraints 
g(1)=-x(1)+0.0193*x(3);
g(2)=-x(2)+0.00954*x(3);
g(3)=-pi*x(3)^2*x(4)-(4/3)*pi*x(3)^3+1296000;
g(4)=x(4)-240;
% If no equality constraint at all, put geq=[] as follows
geq=[];
```

where:

```
0 <= x1 <= 99
0 <= x2 <= 99
10 <= x3 <= 200 
10 <= x4 <= 200 `
```

The result obtained by my algorithm is:

```
x1 = 0.8221372
x2 = 0.4063913
x3 = 42.59778
x4 = 170.5458
```

As you can see, the values of `x1` and `x2` are not multiple of `0.0625`. After checking so many articles, I found that many approaches got the values:

```
x1 = 0.812500
x2 = 0.437500
```

which are multiple of `0.0625`. What needs to be done to force my algorithm to satisfy these constraints.

Comment: I am not familiar with MATLAB but if there is a feature for integer/mixed programming, you can write $x_i=0.0625y_i,i=1,2$ where $y_i$ is integral in the range $\{0,...,\lfloor 99/0.0625\rfloor\}$.

Comment: Although the constraints say $0 \le x_1, x_2 \le 99$, it's probably safe to say $0 \le x_1, x_2 \le 1$.  There are only $17^2 = 289$ pairs $(x_1, x_2)$ in that range where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are multiples of $0.0625$.  Why not try each of those pairs, using Matlab to optimize over $x_3$ and $x_4$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for reply , not sure if I am getting your point , why it's safe to say    0 ≤ x1,x2 ≤1 . Eventhough all the value for x1 and x2 I posted are between 0 and 1 , but for an improved answer those  might not be true and the algorithm needs to find out.

Comment: @RobertIsrael There is a hidden question.  Suppose that someone wanted to (in a very convoluted fashion) partially avoid brute force.  So, they optimize the variables, ignoring the [*multiple of* $0.625$] constraint.  As I am unfamiliar with *optimization theory*, I question: is there an elegant way of then determining which multiples of $0.625$ are optimal, based on the *semi-unconstrained* optimization?